# How does Access-Control-Expose-Headers work in absence of Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, security, xmlhttprequest

I'm implementing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in my API, including sharing custom headers through `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`. In some cases (i.e. id no `Origin` header is present in the request or if the `Origin` header contains a non-whitelisted value, I'm not returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (this is how I understand it should be implemented).

- MAY I in this case still send the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` (as per spec)?
- SHOULD I in this case still send the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` (as per spec)?
- I would expect it to mean in these cases: "These are the headers that you could have seen, if you had sent me the correct `Origin` header, however right now you cannot access them. Is this expectation correct?

I'm afraid [the official specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-expose-headers-response-header) nor the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) seem to address this point; however I'm sure there must be some documentation that addresses this, so any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: The response will be rejected by browser if `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is absence. The client code have no chance to operate the response hence you do not need to worry about this